# JQuery validation error placement

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I am trying to use JQuery validation with ASP.NET MVC4. My intention is when there is any error in the page, it should be displayed before the control. But the error is always displaying next (line) to the control.

Here are the snippets from my JS, cshtml files.

```
$(function () {
$('#Transaction1Screen1').validate({
    errorElement: "div",
    errorLabelContainer: '#errorMessages',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.insertBefore(element);
    }
});

$("#TextBox1").rules("add", { email: true, messages: { email: 'Verify the e-mail in TextBox1' } });

});
```

## bundle mapping

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Common")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/themesCss")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryUI")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/otherControls")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ClientResources")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Transaction1Screen1")
```

## HTML content

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TextBox1, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "TextBox1" }, { "name", "TextBox1" }, { "Class", "txtfield controlWidth" }, { "jsValidation", "checkEMailAddr" } })
<br />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TextBox1)
```

Comment: Doesn't MVC automatically create the code that calls the `.validate()` method? This method cannot be called twice as all subsequent calls are ignored. Look at the ***rendered*** page code to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Try HTML content

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TextBox1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TextBox1, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "TextBox1" }, { "name", "TextBox1" }, { "Class", "txtfield controlWidth" }, { "jsValidation", "checkEMailAddr" } })
```

Comment: This works. However my intention is to define the behavior through script. I have control over the script but not the HTML. So, wherever might be the HTML.Validation object present, I want to display the error message as defined in Script.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize validation like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#Transaction1Screen1").validate({
    errorElement: "span",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
          error.insertBefore(element);
    }
  });
});
```

errorElement attribute means that what element do you wnat to used to wrapp your message.

The element will be placed at new line if you use "div" as your error element.

[image]

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: It seems there is no effect of the change in errorElement. Irrespective whatever I use, the error is displaying  at @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TextBox1)